# Codeigniter - Get one uri param

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking to pass one parameter to my function. Page is sub.mainsite.com/profile/change-password

The profile is the controller and change-password is the function within it. Now I want to pass change-password/first if it is the users first time logging in so the system can redirect them to the home page instead of the profile page.

```
$uri_params = I_WANT_TO_SEE_IF_FIRST_IS_SET;
```

Comment: In CI URI parameters are called segments. Do you know about `$this->uri` (in a controller action)? Instance of `CI_URI`? That has a `$segments` public property? (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this way .

`$uri = $this->uri->segment(3)`
This will retrieve change-password `$uri_params = $uri .'/first';`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are expecting. However, in your controller,

```
public function change_password($first = FALSE) {
    if ($first == FALSE) {
        redirect("profile");
    } else {
        redirect("home");
    }
}
```

By setting default value in controller, you can make it optional. So if there's no value after change_password in your URL, it will assign `$first = FALSE`.